# Issue with an animated, sticky navigation in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an animated sticky navigation, that moves to the top of the document when the user has scrolled past a certain point. It's almost working (and does so fine on the first page load), but when the user scrolls to the top and then scrolls down for a second time, the navigation jumps without the animation. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Here's my jQuery so far:

```
var x = true;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > 150 ){
        x = false;
        $(".header").addClass("pinned");
    }else if( $(document).scrollTop() === 0 ){
        $(".header").removeClass("pinned");
        x = true;
    }
    if(x === false){
        $(".pinned").animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);
    }
});
```

And here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem and what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/DzTRb/4/

Comment: the element style you're applying by using `animate` has a higher priority than the css rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When jquery is doing the animation, it sets `margin-top:0;` after complete, so second time your css class `.pinned` with `margin-top:-100px;` has no effect...

You have to do few things:

- remove any styles added to the `.pinned` element after the animation completes
- run only one animation (check if the `.pinned` class is already added)
- stop the animation when scrolled to top so jquery does not add any more styles

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jg78T/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to also remove your `margin-top` when you've scrolled back to the top of the page.

See my fiddle here;
http://jsfiddle.net/DzTRb/17/
It's a bit temperamental - If you scroll too fast it doesn't seem to remove the margin-top, however, you get the idea.